# Peewee raw SELECT sql with multiple programmatic filter parameters

Tags: python, mysql, sql, peewee

I am facing a problem returning the users from this get_users() function. Here is the code:
I am using Peewee, Pymysql and MySQL

```
    def get_users(self, filter_columns=None,  parameters=[], operator=None, ):
    #Define the operator to be used in the WHERE statement
    if operator:
        operator = operator
    else:
        operator = '&'

    #Contruct the sql_where statement
    where = ''
    if filter_columns:
        for field in filter_columns:
            where = where + field + '=%s, '
    if len(where)>2:
        where = where[:-2]
    #Build Parameter list
    param_list = ''
    for param in parameters:
        param_list = param_list + param + ", "
    if len(param_list)>2:
        param_list = param_list[:-2]

    #Select the users and return.
    sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE " + where
    user = U.raw(sql, param_list)
    return user
```

When i call the function like this:

```
  users = user.get_users(filter_columns=['first_name', 'status'], parameters=['awa', 'active'], operator='|')
print(users)

 for u in users:
     print(u.first_name, u.last_name)
```

This is what i get as result:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/projects/micro bank/tests/smanager/randomtest.py", line 10, in <module>
    for u in users:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2963, in __iter__
    return iter(self.execute())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2959, in execute
    self._qr = QRW(self.model_class, self._execute(), None)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2902, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3758, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

When i print out the user returned, i get this:

```
<class 'common.models.User'> SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name=%s, status=%s ['awa, active']
```

From observation, the problem comes from this last area

#### ['awa, active']

which is supposed to be

#### ['awa', 'active']

The problem now is establishing a parameter_list that when i use it, it should print out like this ['awa',  'active']

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that am using PYTHON 3.4

Comment: This is really really not the way to do things! There's no need for using "raw" SQL here.

Comment: what do you suggest i use @coleifer. The search fields are supplied by the user. which means by default, i don't know whether they will want to filter by first_name, last_name, active etc. So i have to build the filter based on what they supplied. I actually did it to follow the format or Peewee like User.select(built-filter-fields-and-params).get() but it did not work. That's why i resulted to raw SQL but its still giving me issues.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need `param_list` to be `['awa', 'active']`

Try this:

```
param_list = []
for param in parameters:
    param_list.append(param)
# Since `param_list` in needed in the format `'"awa", "active"'`
param_list = ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in param_list)
```

instead of

```
param_list = ''
for param in parameters:
    param_list = param_list + param + ", "
```

Comment: I just tried it and the print out is this: <class 'common.models.User'> SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name=%s, status=%s [['awa', 'active']]

Comment: The double square brackets prevent it from working properly

Comment: the extra bracket gets added internally i think, @Demerit could you please try add this line `param_list = ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in t)` outside the `loop` and using it in `raw`

Comment: Just got this: NameError: name 't' is not defined

Comment: @Demerit, replace `t` with `param_list` :)